# Is there a plan for write access via Stack Overflow API?

Tags: feature-request, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will the API allow posting of questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97770/when-will-the-api-allow-posting-of-questions-and-answers)

Is there a plan for the API to enable developers to log user in and provide write access? Looking at the documentation, the current API is all read-only.

Comment: Making it read-only provides a high degree of safety; IIRC the read-only interface is not provided from the live database, but from a copy.

Comment: The [Roadmap](http://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1) provides a pretty good heads-up about their plans to offer write access for Version 3.0

Answer (score 1):

I think it's on the roadmap.  Try again in 6 to 8 weeks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys! I found the link that tells me everything: [Announcing API version 1.1 and Roadmap](https://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1)